# How do I go directly from FullScreen to Maximized in a QML Window?

Tags: qml, qt5

Below is a small QML application. What I intended was for the application to start full screen, and on the Escape key, change it to maximized:

```js
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    id: topLevelWindow

    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    visibility: Window.FullScreen

    Rectangle {
        id: rect

        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "lightBlue"

        focus: true
        Keys.onPressed: {
            if (event.key === Qt.Key_Escape) {
                rect.color = "lightGreen"

                topLevelWindow.visibility = Window.Maximized
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What actually happens, though, is that it starts full screen as intended, but pressing Escape makes it windowed but ***not*** maximized. Pressing Escape a second time actually maximizes it.

Is there a way to do this without making the user hit Escape twice?

Comment: Could you not put in a line at the end of the script to simulate the pressing of the escape keys for you?  Of if you can get to the HTML code, you could add an onclick event to run some javascript to do that manually if it can't be done in the qml/qt5 code.

Comment: I probably could, or just use a timer or something, but if that's the only workaround for this, then I would consider that a bug.

Comment: Looks like a bug. I get the same result with 5.12. In 6.3 works as expected. Btw `Window.visibility` is enum so I would change it to `visibility: Window.FullScreen`

Comment: Good point. Updated the code.

Thanks for checking on a couple versions! I'll see if I can find it in their bug tracker.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is indeed a bug. Seems like it's [been lingering for a while](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-69888), but (some) newer versions may have fixed it?

In the meantime, it's relatively easy to add a hacky workaround:

```js
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    id: topLevelWindow

    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    visibility: Window.FullScreen

    Rectangle {
        id: rect

        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "lightBlue"

        focus: true
        Keys.onPressed: {
            if (event.key === Qt.Key_Escape) {
                rect.color = "lightGreen"

                topLevelWindow.visibility = Window.Windowed
                windowHackTimer.start()
            }
        }
    }

    Timer {
        id: windowHackTimer
        interval: 0
        repeat: false
        onTriggered: {
            topLevelWindow.visibility = Window.Maximized
        }
    }
}
```

On the button press it becomes windowed, and then after it returns to the event loop (with a 0ms timer), it sets it to maximized. Just setting `topLevelWindow.visibility` multiple times in `Keys.onPressed` doesn't get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should (1) make sure that the Escape key is accepted by your event handler (so that it is not passed down) and (2) schedule the outcome with `Qt.callLater`.

```
        Keys.onPressed: {
            if (event.key === Qt.Key_Escape) {
                event.accepted = true;
                Qt.callLater( greenRectAndMaximize );
            }
        }

        function greenRectAndMaximize() {
            rect.color = "lightGreen";
            topLevelWindow.visibility = Window.Maximized;
        }
```

The `event.accept()` is important to ensure that no other UI will handle the same event. That could be the cause of your problem. The `Qt.callLater` is important because it ensures that your action is added to the end of the windows messaging queue so that the UI/UX for the Escape key (and any other UI/UX events can complete) before we do our action.

Generally, whenever processing events, key presses, button clicks, and so forth, think about what needs to happen now and what needs to be queued for later.

In your case, you have a simple action, but, imagine something more complex such as a button click that triggers a page transition and a sort of 10000 records. The UI/UX is the user clicks the button and we want to see the button animate down and up fully before the action kicks off. If we did it during the event handler, the button may appear to be stuck in the down portion of the animation and the app will appear momentarily hang/crash. So, it is important to understand when we need to queue up actions.

`Qt.callLater` is one of the easiest ways to separate the UI/UX event and the user action and can improve the perceptual responsiveness of your application.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Qt.callLater() works just as well as a timer and is more concise, so that seems like a better workaround. I just skipped event.accept() because this was a tiny example app, but it's a fair point that that should be used diligently.